# adapting some code for mobile uses CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, mobile

i'm trying to use this code ( only Upcoming Events part)
https://codepen.io/AbhijithHebbarK/pen/boKWKE

```
.events-details-list{
     opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:99;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:15px 0px;
     background: #22303E;
}
.events-details-list li{
      padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
.events-details-list li,.events-details-list li:hover{
  color: #fff;
  font-size:15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

when i try to use it on mobile phone, i'm not able to use it as if it was a computer, hover don't work, and font stay red.

maybe someone know a css tip for getting it to work

thanks

Comment: Of course hover doesn't work on a mobile, as it can't detect your finger _above_ the item without actually touching the screen. Indeed, if you tap on the item, the hover effect will be applied

Comment: Hover effects can only be applied on desktop screens, you can see the same effects in mobile after tapping that part

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that would look good on mobile. your not meant to hover on a touchscreen device. But if you still want the animation to happen change it to :active

Answer (score 0):

thx for help, i tried witch active and focus that didn't work
so answer was :

```
  cursor: pointer;
```

and hover works ;)